# Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1302

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I created an MSI installer with WiX 3.8 and I get this error in the MSI log when installing it:

```
InstallFiles: File: Copying new files,  Directory: ,  Size: 
Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Patch 
Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Patch 4: SELECT `Patch`.`File_`, `Patch`.`Header`, `Patch`.`Attributes`, `Patch`.`Sequence`, `Patch`.`StreamRef_` FROM `Patch` WHERE `Patch`.`File_` = ? AND `Patch`.`#_MsiActive`=? ORDER BY `Patch`.`Sequence` 
Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1302 
Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiSFCBypass 
Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: MsiSFCBypass 4: SELECT `File_` FROM `MsiSFCBypass` WHERE `File_` = ? 
Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiPatchHeaders 
Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: MsiPatchHeaders 4: SELECT `Header` FROM `MsiPatchHeaders` WHERE `StreamRef` = ? 
Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiPatchHeaders 
Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
Action ended 19:15:02: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
```

How can I fix this error?
Or maybe it is a known WiX/MSI issue that can be safely ignored?

My WiX script is extremely simple, it just installs a shell extension, so I have no idea where this error comes from.

From the GUI point of view, the installation finishes with no visible problem. All files are present as expected in the target installation folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835(v=vs.85).aspx.  1302 is "Please insert disk".  If you want to clean up these log messages (which are harmless) you can add an error table to your MSI.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear that it's an error anyway, although a potential "insert the disk" situation looks worrying. The other stuff is just that it wants to know if there is any patch sequencing going on, and that requires looking in the Patch table. Since there isn't a patch table that's ok, no sequencing is required. It's the same with those others, 2205 and 2228 are both variations on "no table".

Sometimes installing a patch will require the original MSI file if the installed product isn't quite correct. If it required that MSI file then you would have seen that error and been asked to insert the disk, but if you have a custom message in the Error table it wants to know what it is.

Remember this is a debugging log primarily intended for diagnosing issues with an install. The fact that it says "error" doesn't mean that there are any - as you can seem it logs an "error" every time it makes a query on a table in case that table is there and contains extra information.